# wordpress category page 404

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have updated a category slug and now my category page for that category is displaying a 404. I have tested doing this on a staging site and it works fine but when I do this on production for some reason I get a 404.
I have,

- resaved permalinks hundreds of times
- deactivated plugins
- disabled all caching
- restarted my server

I am completely confused and cannot understand why wordpress is so fragile around permalinks and urls.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried deleting the content of your .htaccess and then resaving permalinks?

Comment: i think you should reset Settings -> Permalinks on production server, so it will rewrite your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I went to `Settings > Permalink`, I changed nothing, validated and... it worked. Perhaps a default setting was missing.